# How can I transfer files between directories with ftp using SSIS?

Tags: ftp, ssis

How can I transfer files between directories with ftp using SSIS?

I know I can delete and re-upload the file, but is there an easier way?

I want to transfer a file I finished with to an 'Archive' folder.

Comment: When you say Archive, do you mean to say that even thats on a FTP location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theoretical answer is you would use the combination of the commands RNFR (rename from)/RNTO (rename to) to rename (move) a file. Within your FTP session, you'd issue a command like

```
ftp> rnfr /src/test/done.txt
ftp> rnto /src/test/Archive/done.txt
```

I say theoretical as my testing using the Windows command-line FTP client (system32\ftp.exe) connecting to a z/OS ftp server would result in the client indicating RNFR/RNTO is an `Invalid command`

The windows client *does* implement a **rename** method which under the sheets seems to issue RNFR/RNTO.

A simple rename looks like

```
ftp> rename empty.txt e.txt
350 RNFR accepted. Please supply new name for RNTO.
250 /src/test/empty.txt renamed to /src/test/e.txt
```

However, I could not get it to move under a directory

```
ftp> rename empty.txt Archive
350 RNFR accepted. Please supply new name for RNTO.
550 RNTO fails: /src/test/Archive is a directory.

ftp> rename empty.txt Archive/
350 RNFR accepted. Please supply new name for RNTO.
550 RNTO fails: /src/test/Archive/ is a directory.

ftp> rename empty.txt Archive/emp.txt
350 RNFR accepted. Please supply new name for RNTO.
550 Renaming attempt failed. Rc was 111
```

I don't know if this is a failing of the client implementation or the server (or both). Or, it might just be an insufficient set of [permissions](http://ktomiak.biz/ORG/STUFF/tips/UNIX008.html) for my credentials.

### How does this apply to SSIS?

Whatever steps it takes for you to get the rename working in a command line is going to be the same set of commands you'll want to issue. If you're using the built-in `FTP Task`, you'll see there is no rename available to you. You may also discover that it's one of the most blecherous tasks in the toolbox. Instead, I am a strong advocate of either using a command file for the windows [FTP client](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269) or using the .NET [FTP library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)

### References

- RFC on FTP describing what standard command should page (page 31) https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959
- Examples of common FTP commands http://www.hiteksoftware.com/help/English/FtpCommands.htm
- An example of how RNFR/RNTO should work http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/2218